# Knocking in rear

Tags: jeep, patriot

So I got a 2015 Jeep Patriot and when I’m driving at lower speeds and I accelerate there’s a loud knocking noise coming from the rear and under my jeep. I have no clue what it could be. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the jeep AWD or FWD only?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It's most likely suspension related. Park the Jeep on a flat surface, put the parking brake on, then leave it in neutral. Check to ensure the Jeep isn't moving (you might want to chock the wheels). Then crawl under the Jeep and *violently* try to move suspension parts. Jiggle everything and see if you can figure it out. Ensure you check the shocks top and bottom.

Comment: Check the prop shaft uj’s

Comment: Check the rear drive shaft u joints for failure.